# Error WorkflowScript: 8: Expected one of "steps", "stages", or "parallel" for stage "check out scm" when need to run a pipeline

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I write this pipeline for run that after push on the develop branch or master branch and doing some workers related to that branch.

I want to check the repository and run pipeline after push on the any branches

```js
pipeline {
    triggers {
        pollSCM('*/1 * * * * ')
    }
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Check out scm') {
            when {
                branch 'master'
            }
            checkout scm
        }
        stage('Install npm') {
            steps {
                sh 'npm install'
            }
        }
        stage('Build Project Develop') {
            when {
                branch 'develop'
            }
            steps {
                sh 'ng build --prod '
            }
        }
        stage('Build Project Realase')
        {
            when {
                branch 'master'
            }
            steps {
                sh 'ng build --prod '
            }
        }
        stage('Move to Var') {
            steps {
                sh 'chown -R root:jenkins /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Angular-CI-CD--Test_master/dist/ang-CICD/. && /var/www/html'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it shows me this error:

```
Branch indexing
Connecting to https://api.github.com using kiadr9372/****** (GitHub Access Token)
Obtained Jenkinsfile from d57840a79c46a88969381cc978f378c7d6804cec
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
GitHub has been notified of this commit’s build result
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 8: Unknown stage section "checkout". Starting with version 0.5, steps in a stage must be in a ‘steps’ block. @ line 8, column 9.
stage('check out scm') {
    ^
    WorkflowScript: 8: Expected one of "steps", "stages", or "parallel" for stage "check out scm" @ line 8, column 9.
    stage('check out scm') {
        ^
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Did you read the error message? Your `checkout scm` should be inside `steps {...}`: `steps { checkout scm }`

Comment: @MaratC i have a problem with this . when i push in the develop branch it not run the ipline in jenkines i just must push on the maste rbranch for run the projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

You need to place `checkout scm` within a step closure.  You also have an additional closing bracket.

```js
pipeline {
    triggers {
        pollSCM('*/1 * * * * ')
    }
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('check out scm') {
            when {
                branch 'master'
            }
            steps {
                checkout scm
            }
        }
        stage('Install npm') {
            steps {
                sh 'npm install'
            }
        }
        stage('Build Project Develop') {
            when {
                branch 'develop'
            }
            steps {
                sh 'ng build --prod '
            }
        }
        stage('Build Project Realase') {
            when {
                branch 'master'
            }
            steps {
                sh 'ng build --prod '
            }
        }
        stage('Move to Var') {
            steps {
                sh 'chown -R root:jenkins /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Angular-CI-CD--Test_master/dist/ang-CICD/. && /var/www/html'
            }
        }
    }
}
```